# Express validator- validate array of objects as request body

Tags: wildcard, express-validator

I am trying to validate array of objects using wildcards. The req.body will be just an array of objects.

```
[{id:1},
  {id:2}
]
```

If it was of this format

```
{
  array: [{id:1}]
}
```

wild card would be array.*.id;

What am I doing wrong here.
I looked into github issue in express-validator repo and was trying follow this https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator/issues/67#issuecomment-410874697

```
const app = require("express")();
const {
    validationResult,
    body
} = require('express-validator');

app.post("/post",
[body().not().isArray().withMessage("success"),
body("*.id").not().isEmpty().withMessage("yeaaaa")],
(req,res,next)=>{
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }
    res.send("Passed validation")
})

app.listen(3000,()=>console.log("running on express !!!"))
```

Comment: I posted this question in the Github repository (https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator/issues/1165) because I also have the same issue.
Did you, by any change, find a way to make it work?